# How to cut certain field in a file and insert in middle of another file in unix

Tags: xml, shell, awk, scripting

I have a file like below with "|" delimited.

```
1234|This is Line 1|Yes
5678|This is Line 2|Yes
9999|This is Line 3|Yes
```

I already have a XML file and I want to insert 1st,2nd,3rd column in different positions and create 1 XML file for each line like below

```
<tag1>1234</tag1> 
<tag2> This is line 1 </tag2>
<tag3> Yes </tag3>
```

Basically I want to read every line from the first file and create a XML file for each line by inserting the fields in different positions. Any help of how to do it in shell scripting would be of great help

I tried this, but for loop is not reading 2nd column properly("This is Line 1").it is taking  each space as a field and create multiple files

```
  for i in `cat file | awk -F"|" '{print $1}'`
    do
    echo $i
    j=`cat addxml | grep "tag2" | awk -F ">" -v var="$i" '{print $1">"var$2">"}'`
    sed 's|<tag2></tag2>|'"${j}"'|g' addxml > input1.xml
    done
```

Comment: Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some of the reasons why you have the completely wrong approach.  Also google UUOC, "deprecated backticks", and "quote your variables" to understand some of your additional syntax issues. Then read the book Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to do this the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just say...

```
awk -F"|" '{file="file_"NR
            for (i=1;i<=3;i++) 
                printf "<tag%d>%s</tag%d>\n", i, $i, i >> file
           }' file
```

so you have files like:

```
$ tail file*
==> file_1 <==
<tag1>1234</tag1>
<tag2>This is Line 1</tag2>
<tag3>Yes</tag3>

==> file_2 <==
<tag1>5678</tag1>
<tag2>This is Line 2</tag2>
<tag3>Yes</tag3>

==> file_3 <==
<tag1>9999</tag1>
<tag2>This is Line 3</tag2>
<tag3>Yes</tag3>
```

Comment: I think the problem here is for loop is reading the 2nd column as 3 lines with "," separated like.

      This  \n
       is \n
       Line \n 
       2  \n
(each word in 1 line)
Instead of reading : "This is Line 2". I tried setting IFS in for loop but I don't know how to read only 2nd feild after setting IFS as"|"

Comment: @SenthilkumarDuraisamy - what problem? The script seems to be doing exatly what you asked for. If it's not then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @EdMorton aaah ok, thanks! (I am placing your comments in [the edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37748041/revisions) so that I can still learn from them in the future :D)

Comment: I'm sorry .. Could you please clarify what is $i in the print statement. printf "<tag%d>%s</tag%d>\n", i, $i, i

Comment: @SenthilkumarDuraisamy `$i` is the field in the position `i`. That is, `print $1` will return the first field. And since we are looping through the number of fields, this prints a field every time.

Comment: got it .. Thanks!. Actually I want to insert these tags in a XML file . For example the XML file would ,be having many tags and I want to replace <tag1></tag1> to <tag1>1234</tag1>. Basically I want to insert the entries into that XML file

Comment: @SenthilkumarDuraisamy uhms, that is a different question then. Try to use my current answer and do some research on how to replace lines. Also, `awk` is not the way to edit XMLs. Use a language with proper XML handling for that.

Comment: Sure.. I can use sed again to change it.. Thanks for your time

Comment: awk -F"|" '{for (i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
                if ( i=="1")
{
printf  "<ns1:id>%s</ns1:id>|", $i
}
                else if ( i=="2")
{
printf "<ns2:content>%s</ns2:content>|\n",$i
}
}
           }' file..                  Here I want to assign the printf output to a varibale.. I tried many things but nothing is working. Could you please help

Comment: @SenthilkumarDuraisamy thaht is a matter for another question. Comments are not for extended questions because it is complicated to get to know what exactly what you are asking.